# Can't connect to MSSQL DB through Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, sql-server, apache, tomcat, jdbc

I'm trying to set up `Geoportal 1.2.7`, running on `Apache Tomcat 8.5.6`, `MSSQL Server 2012, JDK 8, and jdbc 4`. I can log into the Geoportal, but when I go to the Administration tab, I get the error

> "A database communication error has occurred"

Checking the Apache logfiles, I see there's a severe error

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The
>   port number 1433:geoportal is not valid.)

I have tried a range of different entries in the config for the jdbc, but it always comes back to that error.

```
<Context docBase="geoportal" path="/geoportal" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true">
    <Resources
         cachingAllowed="true"
         cacheMaxSize="100000"
     />
    <Resource name="jdbc/gpt" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDEMOSERVER:1433:geoportal"
              user="******"
              password="*******"  
              maxTotal="20"
              maxIdle="10"
              maxWaitMillis="-1" />
</Context>
```

That is just my latest attempt. I have seen conflicting posts all over the net about exactly what the url should look like.

I have tried  `url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDEMOSERVER:1433;databaseName=geoportal" (Geoportal won't launch),  url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDEMOSERVER:1433/databaseName=geoportal" (Then I get the port error),  url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDEMOSERVER:1433" (Geoportal won't load).`

I'm at my wits end. I checked the rest of the config files carefully, and the editing within them was minimal and probably has no play on the error.

If anyone could point out my mistake it would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx) for the correct URL format. Note that depending on the config, port 1433 might not be correct. Also make sure the discern between the instance name of the database (if any), and database names on that instance.

Comment: I am having problems while using postgres db. Any help on how this got fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
url="jdbc:sqlserver://SQLDEMOSERVER:1433/geoportal
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gave me the same error on the Administration tab, as well as the log file.

Comment: Is the database running?

Comment: Yes, the SQL database is running. I made sure the TCP/IP protocol is also active. I also double-checked the compatibility between all the softwares in question on the Esri website.

Comment: Is SQLDEMOSERVER the host name? Esri docs say to use postgre sql at port 5432. Did you change the port before DB setup?

Comment: I'm trying to have it work with MS SQL. It works fine with PostgreSQL, but the client is running a MS SQL server.

Comment: SQLDEMOSERVER is the name of the server. I tried localhost and the 127 ip address as well, and they all have the same result.

Comment: Well. This is weird. I am afraid I can't help out.

Answer (score 0):

These URLs work for me on SQL Server 2012:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=test
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=test
```

This does not work for me in SQL Server 2012 but might work with older versions:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test
```

These do not work at all:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/databaseName=test
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433:test
```

I suppose the problem is elsewhere (investigate the "won't launch" problem in more detail).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will have a look at the rest of the applications.